# Hoffman and Kunze big list?

Tags: support

I recently think I came across a post either here or on the main site containing most of the questions that have been asked from Hoffman and Kunze’s Linear Algebra on this site. Could someone link it please? Or has it been deleted since?

Comment: Looking at [this older discussion on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27658), I see that this question is mentioned: [Is there a list of all typos in Hoffman and Kunze, Linear Algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/437253) But that is a list of *typos* - not list of *questions*.

Comment: If such question exists *on the main site*, it is most likely tagged ([tag:linear-algebra]). And the question you describe would probably have many linked questions - so you could try to browse [the frequent tab of this tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra?tab=Frequent) to see whether you're able to find that question. 
Or you might try searching with SEDE - in that way, you can check deleted questions, too. Some queries [are suggested here in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2022/10/28).

Comment: Even if it has been deleted, I'd like such a list to be context-edited and reinstated. I'll take that responsibility. Innumerable people are likely to benefit from such a question.

Comment: By the way, I remember a comment on the post I mentioned saying that it should have a big-list tag.

Comment: A user logging in as "Avenger" posted many questions about that book. You'll find many of them at https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A775699+Kunze

Comment: By any chance aren't you talking about this question: [A list of questions on Boyd & Vandenberghe](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414). It is about a different book - but there is a [comment suggesting to use the tag big-list](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/158440).

Comment: Ah ****, this is embarrassing. Yes I saw this, then started studying H&K, and somehow managed to connect them both. I apologise.